# Openshift nodejs javascript file location

Tags: node.js, filepath, openshift

I push my application with Git bash in Openshift nodejs.
My sass1.js file is in the js folder.
In my index.html file I refer to it as

```
<script src="./js/sass1.js"></script>
```

But I get this error in when I look in Firefox

"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - ...js/sass1.js"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to reference your code locations with the appropriate environment variable. You can also check out https://www.openshift.com/videos/getting-started-with-nodejs-on-openshift for more information on nodejs with openshift.

**EDIT**

On second thought I think this thread will point you in the right direction https://www.openshift.com/forums/openshift/pictures-css-where-can-i-store-resources.

Comment: Yes, The references you cited were helpful.

Comment: For someone who might run into similar problem, I have given below the code which worked in Server.Js

Comment: self.initializeServer = function() {
          self.createRoutes();
          self.app = express.createServer();
        ['css', 'img', 'js', 'plugin', 'lib'].forEach(function       (dir)  {
            self.app.use('/'+dir, express.static(__dirname+'/'+dir));
            });

        //  Add handlers for the app (from the routes).
        for (var r in self.routes) {
            self.app.get(r, self.routes[r]);
        }
    };

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide static directory to nodejs express app.

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname+"/yourfolderwherecssisresiding")
```